# The "Actions" tab on GitHub is missing

Tags: github, github-actions, github-enterprise

I'm trying to create a GitHub action, but the "Actions" tab doesn't exist in my repository:

[image: Image of Missing Actions tab]

[This GitHub documentation page](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/managing-repository-settings/disabling-or-limiting-github-actions-for-a-repository) advised navigating to the "Settings" tab, then selecting "Actions" from the left sidebar and enabling them.

[image: Image of missing Actions tab from Settings tab]

My next thought was that my organization disabled actions, so I followed the steps on [this GitHub documentation page](https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/managing-organization-settings/disabling-or-limiting-github-actions-for-your-organization) about managing actions for your organization. But again, I go to Your organizations -> Settings and look for "Actions" in the left sidebar, and it's nowhere to be found.

[image: Image of missing Actions tab from organization settings]

Then I think that maybe I'm missing Admin privileges, so I check the "People" tab under my organization, and I'm an "Owner," which [my research tells me](https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/managing-peoples-access-to-your-organization-with-roles/permission-levels-for-an-organization) is the same as Admin.

[image: Image of Owner Privileges]

So here we are. Any ideas as to why the Actions tab is missing from everywhere in my organization?

Comment: Is your enterprise Blob storage configured? [reference](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.0/admin/github-actions/enabling-github-actions-for-github-enterprise-server/getting-started-with-github-actions-for-github-enterprise-server#external-storage-requirements). I also saw someone with the same problem solving it configuring it [here](https://github.community/t/actions-tab-missing/16696/5).

Comment: This is definitely moving me in the right direction, but I'm getting lost at the first step: "From an administrative account on GitHub Enterprise Server, click [rocket ship] in the upper-right corner of any page." I don't see the rocket ship symbol when I'm logged into GitHub, even though it's an Enterprise account. Is GitHub Enterprise Server a different thing entirely?

Comment: It depends the kind of organization and plan you use. [reference](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/learning-about-github/types-of-github-accounts#organization-accounts). It can be free, or not.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I wasn't able to solve my problem, I'm going to mark it as resolved - see GuiFalourd's comment about configuring Blob storage (references [here](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.0/admin/github-actions/enabling-github-actions-for-github-enterprise-server/getting-started-with-github-actions-for-github-enterprise-server#external-storage-requirements) and [here](https://github.community/t/actions-tab-missing/16696)). I don't think my organization has a GitHub Enterprise Server account, and it looks like you need to pay extra for services like that. So while I can't solve the problem myself, hopefully this points someone with the same problem in the right direction.

Comment: GitHub Free and GitHub Teams both support actions, I ran across this same issue a few days ago as I wanted to setup a self-hosted runner. However we were using a GitHub Legacy plan which doesn't support actions, migrating to GitHub Teams solved the issue

Answer (score 21):

I had to go to `Settings > Action > Allow all actions`[image]